# Solve the integral equation for $f$.

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

Find all functions $f$ that satisfy:
$$\int f(x)dx \cdot \int (1/f(x))dx = -1$$ So far, I have tried a handful of methods. I have substituted a variable $u$ for $f(x)$, I have substituted an antiderivative $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ for the first and second integrands, respectively. Using this second method, I thought I was on the right track until coming to: $$f(x) = \pm 1/\int f(x)dx$$ Any helpful replies are appreciated, but this problem *is* solvable using relatively basic methods. This problem is from Stewart's *Early Transcendentals*.

Comment: Didn't you get $f^2=(\int f)^2$ ?

Comment: Is $\int$ an indefinite integral?  For problems in an elementary textbook: look at what was covered just before this in the book.

Comment: It is an indefinite integral. It is an end-of-chapter review of beginner differential equations. The book briefly introduced integral equations, but it was also part of a problem set in which they were brought up. It's a comprehensive book on calculus A-C, and this was found on page 633 of 1100.

Comment: Also take into account that Stewart's book are poor quality books. They are full of imprecisions, things that are not explained or presented properly. The statement of this exercise is one.